# Questions on trigonometry and vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, trigonometry, vector-spaces

I found a pseudocode on the web and I have a question about it.
Assume we have vector $\begin{bmatrix}a\\b \end{bmatrix}$ as input. The outputs are $cos(\theta)$ as $c$ , and $sin(\theta)$ as $s$ for some $\theta$.

$If \quad (b==0)$

$\quad\quad c = 1$

$\quad\quad s = 0$

$else \quad  If \quad (|b|>|a|)$

$\quad\quad \tau = \frac{-a}{b}$

$ \quad\quad s = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\tau^{2}}}$

$\quad\quad c = s*\tau $

$else$

$\quad\quad \tau = \frac{-b}{a}$

$ \quad\quad c = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\tau^{2}}}$

$\quad\quad s = c*\tau $

$end$

I understood how  the following theorems and facts were used to write the pseudocode.
$$tan(\theta) = \frac {opposite}{adjacent}$$
$$ tan ^{2} (\theta) +1 =\frac{1}{cos^{2}(\theta)}$$ 
$$ tan(\theta) = \frac {sin(\theta)}{cos(\theta) }$$
My question is why the conditions of $ |a| < |b| $ and $|a| > |b|$ are separated? How this is related to the sign of $\theta$ ?

Comment: Your code will find the smaller of the angle between the x axis and the y axis.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Then the assumption that $\theta$ is the angle between vector and $x$-axis is not valid.

Comment: I was going to say that there was a problem with the signs as well.  More conventional...$\cos \theta = \frac {a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}, \sin \theta = \frac {b}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}, \tan \theta = \frac {b}{a}$